# sed replace hash with another hash in a file

Tags: bash, sed

let's say that I have a file with the following format:

```
name type 3425sdfsg125 url
```

between every entry (i.e name and type) is a variable amount of whitespace characters.

I want to replace the hash value 3425... with another hash value that is stored in ${hash} variable:

```
hash=48956sdglj23
```

the result should be:

```
name type 48956sdglj23 url
```

how would one do such a thing using sed?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you do not have the exact value to replace?
Does this work?

```
sed -i "s/y   .* z/y   $hash z/g" foo
```

Comment: Well, I just checked and it worked for me:
  
`$ cat foo`  
`name type 3425sdfsg125 url`  
  
`$ sed "s/e .* u/e $hash u/g" foo`  
`name 48956sdglj23 url`  

If this does not work, is there a more full example of what needs to be accomplished?

Comment: Maybe it would be better like this: `sed "s/type .* url/type $hash url/g"`
So it changes everything between "type " and " url" as ".*" represents any number of any characters.

Comment: this works but is it possible to keep the whitespace as in the original file? thanks again

Comment: Yeah, in my examples I have the same whitespaces as in the file. Just need to include them to the command. As you can see, in the original answer, there are three whitespaces after "y" and that works.

Answer (score 0):

Robustly with GNU sed:

```
$ echo 'name    type   3425sdfsg125    url' |
    sed -E 's/^(\s*name\s+type\s+)\S+(\s+url\s*)$/\1'"$hash"'\2/'
name    type   48956sdglj23    url
```

and any POSIX sed:

```
$ echo 'name    type   3425sdfsg125    url' |
    sed 's/^\([[:space:]]*name[[:space:]]\{1,\}type[[:space:]]\{1,\}\)[^[:space:]]\{1,\}\([[:space:]]\{1,\}url[[:space:]]*\)$/\1'"$hash"'\2/'
name    type   48956sdglj23    url
```